# List not being initialized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

In my system to register products for customers, I'm having the exception *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
My code:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PurchasedProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class PurchasedProduct
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public static List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

private void buttonRegisterProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer procli = Customers[customersListBox.SelectedIndex];
        PurchasedProduct procomp = new PurchasedProduct();
        procomp.ProductName = PurchasedProductTextBox.Text;
        procli.Products.Add(procomp);
        PurchasedProductsListBox.Items.Add(procomp.ProductName);
    }
```

I'm getting the exception *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* in this line:

```
procli.Products.Add(procomp);
```

I apreciate any help.

**EDIT**
After a time trying and thinking, I managed by this way:

```
private void buttonRegisterProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer procli = Customers[customersListBox.SelectedIndex];
    PurchasedProduct procomp = new PurchasedProduct();
    if(procli.Products == null)
    {
        procli.Products = new List<PurchasedProduct>
        {
            new PurchasedProduct
            {
                ProductName = PurchasedProductTextBox.Text
            }
        };
        PurchasedProductsListBox.Items.Add(procli.Products[0].ProductName);
    }
    else
    {
        procomp.ProductName = PurchasedProductTextBox.Text;
        procli.Products.Add(procomp);
        PurchasedProductsListBox.Items.Add(procomp.ProductName);
    }
}
```

This worked, but I would like more explanation about this code that I reached.
Anyway, I'd be grateful if someone present a better and more comprehensive solution.

Comment: your `List<PurchasedProduct> Products` is not initialized anywhere. Either new it in the `Customer` class or in your click event.

Comment: Null exceptions are always the same thing.  You are trying to access the property of an object that is null.  In your case, you index into `Customers` to get `procli` but its `Products` is not initialized, so you cant call `Add`.

Comment: @paqogomez humm how about `PurchasedProduct procomp = new PurchasedProduct();`? 
I thought this would solve the problem.

Comment: @ethorn10 Yes, I do not know how to initialize the List with the logic of the code.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve it. `procli.Products` is what isn't initialized. You can't add the new `PurchasedProduct` to something (`procli.Products`) without it being initialized.

Comment: @ethorn10 I thought the problem was because of `procomp`, so is the `procli` instance. I need to initialize this in the actual code but I don't know how.

Comment: google how to initialize new objects if you don't know this then why are you programming.. this is quite basic actually

Comment: Read the duplicate link to this question.  It is an EXCELLENT review of all of the ways you can get null exceptions.  Your variation is explained well.

Comment: @paqogomez After a long time thinking I've reached a point. I have updated the question. Please see my edition and help me to understand my new code that worked, but I do not know if is the best solution.

Comment: I'm sure this works, however, I would offer these suggestions.  Instead of doing a new in your event handler, move the new to the constructor of `Customers`.  Perhaps even in the property, like in my next comment.

Comment: `private PurchasedProduct _products; public PurchasedProduct Products { get { if (_products == null) _products = new PurchasedProduct(); return _products; }`

Comment: Additionally, it is not very OO to put code in your event handler.  Move all that code into a method that can be reused and call it from your event handler.

Comment: @paqogomez can you post an answer with this new solution and how to implement in my code?

Comment: This question is closed. No new answers can be posted.